# VGAM fitting a betabinomial model

Tags: r, beta-binomial-distribution

I have a small question, given this:

```
fit <- vglm(cbind(R, N-R) ~ 1, betabinomial, lirat, trace=TRUE, subset=(N > 1))
```

Why should I do `cbind(R, N-R)`? Can someone explain this simple step to me? If I leave out that part, I get an error saying that I can only fit `0, 1`. But in the example [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/VGAM/docs/betabinomial), $Y$ can contain a lot of different values.

Comment: Although the question explicitly asks about R code, the real issue is understanding the nature of the beta binomial distribution--ie, a statistical issue. The issue & the answer would be the same for any software. This should be on topic here, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is the distribution of the number of 'successes' out of a known, finite number of 'trials' (e.g., heads on a certain number of coin flips).  With a fixed probability of success, $\pi$, and a fixed number of trials, $n$, the variance of the number of successes is fixed as well.  A typical logistic regression scenario has [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) data (a single coin flip) as its response, but when you have binomial data with $n>1$ per observation, you can find that the response data vary more than they ought to.  In that case, the assumptions of a binomial GLiM will be violated.

The [beta binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) relaxes that assumption.  It contains three parameters, $n, \alpha, \& \beta$, which gives it additional flexibility to address the [overdispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion) in the situation described above.  The important point here, though, is that the overdispersion / greater variance can only exist with data that are counts of successes out of $n>1$ trials.  Thus, `R` (or any other software) needs the data to be in that form to fit the model.  `SAS`, for example, uses [events/trials](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect010.htm); `R` uses `cbind(successes, failures)`, which is equivalent.  (For what it's worth, in the documentation page you link to, I see only `cbind(successes, failures)` in the examples listed.)